# How do I replace value between xml tag in a file by using shell scripting sed command?

Tags: xml, sed

I have a configuration file. Ex: config.xml It has following configurations.

```
    <!-- Admin username for the Authentication manager. -->
    <Username>adminusername</Username>
    <!-- Admin password for the Authentication manager. -->
    <Password>adminpassword}</Password>
```

I need to change the value "adminusername" and "adminpassword" by running a shell script. How can I achieve this using sed?

Comment: sed is not a good choice to work on xml input, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794995/find-and-replace-in-xml-file-using-sed

Answer (score 1):

Sed is not the right tool for the job. Use an XML-aware tool that can really parse the XML.

For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) I happen to maintain, you can write

```
open config.xml ;
set /Root/Username "newname" ;
set /Root/Password "newpassword" ;
save :b ;
```

(Provided the XML's root element is called `Root`, the mentioned elements are its children, and they aren't repeated.)

Comment: I hadn't come across xsh. Another similar tool is xmlsh - www.xmlsh.org