# Extract CString between tags

Tags: mfc, tags, extract, atl, cstring

How can I extract a CString between two tags ?

```
 <tag1>My Text</tag1>
```

I don't want to calculate the start and end position then use Mid, maybe there is another easier method using STL ?

Comment: Why on god's green earth are you parsing HTML/XML with MFC and CString?

Comment: Is there a reason to not use an XML parser library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: the following idea is [bad](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) and [should not be used in production code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335250/parsing-xml-with-regex-in-java). I'm assuming you just want a quick hack for testing.

Use a regular expression to match the tags. [Microsoft provides this in CAtlRegExp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/mfcregex.aspx). If you're using Visual Studio 2008 or newer, [download ATL here](https://atlserver.codeplex.com/). Then, just provide `myString` to the code below:

```
#include "atlrx.h"
CAtlRegExp<> regex;
VERIFY( REPARSE_ERROR_OK == regex.Parse("<tag1>(.*)</tag1>") );

CAtlREMatchContext<> mc;
if (!regex.Match(myString, &mc)) {
    // no match found
} else {
    // match(es) found
    for (UINT nGroupIndex = 0; nGroupIndex < mc.m_uNumGroups; ++nGroupIndex) {
        const CAtlREMatchContext<>::RECHAR* szStart = 0;
        const CAtlREMatchContext<>::RECHAR* szEnd = 0;
        mc.GetMatch(nGroupIndex, &szStart, &szEnd);
        ptrdiff_t nLength = szEnd - szStart;
        CString text(szStart, nLength);
        // now do something with text
    }
}
```

Disclaimer 2: You really should use [an XML parser library instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686/best-open-xml-parser-for-c).

Comment: I need to extract just a few custom elements, not an entire html file