# How to define a pattern in macro in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a file having too many section like

```
 [Section]

 [Section.Ia32]

 [Section.x64].... so more
```

so, I need to define single macro to when parsing the file we can get the section using one macro. currently I am trying like,

```
#define APattern = "(^(\\s)*\\[Section(\\.\\w+)*\\])";
```

it's compile succesfully... but it is not working.

For e.g

```
  CString a = Section;
  a.compareNoCase(APattern);
```

it is not working..

thanks

Comment: `#define APatter "(^(\\s)*\\[Section(\\.\\w+)*\\])"` (no `=` or `;`) would be a starting point. I'm not sure if that actually helps you or not, as I'm not entirely sure what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I'd suggest `const CString APattern = "..."` instead. No justification at all for a macro here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax in your define is incorrect. In c++ a
    define
is without

```
    "=",
```

rather like

```
    #define SQR(a) (a * a).
```

So in your define an argument is missing as well. Do not use the

```
     ";"
```

at the end of the line.
And for second, you are passing the result as an argument to the function

```
    a.compareNoCase(),
```

which might be incorrect in meaning of which type is returned by your define.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 problems, the first one, regarding C macro syntax, rightly addressed by fiscblog answer (+1), the other is that seems you are actually expecting a *regular expression* match, that is over CString capabilities. See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8660900/874024) to get regular expressions matching working in Visual C++

To be true, I would address the problem using sscanf, more or less like

```
#define ASection(In, Section) (sscanf(In, " [Section(%^[)])", Section) == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

With #define everything you have after the name is just pasted. So for yuor example the result will be:

```
CString a = Section;
a.compareNoCase( = "(^(\\s)*\\[Section(\\.\\w+)*\\])"; );
```

You can see for yourself it is invalid syntax. For correct definition you an go backwards:

```
a.compareNoCase( "(^(\\s)*\\[Section(\\.\\w+)*\\])" );
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
-->
#define APattern "(^(\\s)*\\[Section(\\.\\w+)*\\])"
```