# How to scrape strings inside given tags?

Tags: java, android, xml, string

I have a XML read into a one single `String`. I need to get all the data inside `<code>` tags. I do not need to go though whole XML file parsing them. Can i use  a simple string processing technique to get the data inside those tags.

```
input : <a><b><code>Hello</code></b><code>World</code></a>

output : Hello, World
```

Comment: If that syntax is always the same or very regular you can probably use regular expressions. But it's way safer if you use some real XML processing like http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example

Comment: can you suggest how to create a regular expression for above? and how to call it? Thank you

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335250/parsing-xml-with-regex-in-java `"<code>(.*?)</code>"` would match your code tags and `matcher.group(1)` would contain the text. But be aware that this is not going to work (or needs way more complicated regexes) if the xml could be like `< code attribute="something">` or can contain `<code>` or other tags inside `<code>` etc. XML is not a regular language so there are cases that can't be done with regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is *not* an advisable tool to play with XML, specially when there are sophiticated many parsers are there. You may use `javax.xml.xpath` package to do this stuff for you like:

```
    XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nl =  (NodeList)xp.evaluate("//code", new InputSource(new StringReader("<a><b><code>Hello</code></b><code>World</code></a>")), XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for(int i=0; i< nl.getLength(); i++){
        System.out.print(nl.item(i).getTextContent()+", ");
    }
```

will result

```
Hello, World,
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/): it's simple.