# Dart: regexp to parse multiline xml document

Tags: xml, regex, dart

I am trying to parse simple XML file like this:

```dart
<root>
    <subroot>
        <subsubroot>
        test
        </subsubroot>
    </subroot>
</root>
```

I use following code for this:

```dart
#import('dart:core');
#import('dart:io');

class XMLParser {
  parse( File file ) {
    String xml = file.readAsTextSync();
    xml = xml.trim();
    //xml = xml.replaceAll("\n", "");
    print(xml);
    RegExp p = new RegExp("<([^<>]+)>(.*)</\\1>", true);
    Iterable it = p.allMatches(xml);
    print(it);
    Iterator itt = it.iterator();
    while( itt.hasNext() ) {
      print(itt.next().group(0));
    }
  }
}

main() {
  new XMLParser().parse(new File("test.xml"));
}
```

It looks like it does not work even for *multiline* parameter set to true.
When I remove all newline symbols from the file it is ok.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a time to report a bug :)?

Comment: This will not answer your regexp woes directly, but I would recommend reading [this Coding Horror post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) (and please take it as a helpful pointer, not as an attack).

Comment: I am not sure what should I get from there :) Should I look for Dart html/xml parser to parse xml?

Comment: @firen you should report a bug that Dart needs to add a XML parser. XML documents cannot properly be handled by regular expressions.

Comment: yeah I already did that sometime ago and yes this is not answer for my question and no I am not planning to write full xml parser just simple one for some strings replacement which I will use till dart team will provide their xml parser for VM

Comment: @firen I understand, I have updated the answer with a link to a XML parser written in Dart

Answer (score 1):

XML cannot properly be parsed by Regular expressions (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335250/parsing-xml-with-regex-in-java) post for more info) and Dart does currently not ship with a XML parser in its SDK. However there does exists open source Dart XML parser [here](https://github.com/prujohn/dart-xml).