# extract text between xml comments in regex

Tags: regex

I need to extract text from XML as follows:

`...some xml code...

<!-- start -->

text to

be extracted

<!-- end -->

...some xml code...`


I need a regular expression to output:
text to
be extracted

I tried something like:

(?<=\<!--\s*start\s*-->)(.*)(?=\<!--\s*end\s*-->)

any ides?

Comment: Why don't you use an XML-parser instead? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335250/parsing-xml-with-regex-in-java)

Comment: or, if you want, you need a key `s`, that allows to `.` eat `\n`. So, you have multi-line, that separated by `\n`. `.`-symbol doesn't match `\n` general, but also need a key

Comment: Your regular expression should work if you enable single line mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one did the trick:

`(?<=\<!--\s*start\s*-->)((?s).*)(?=\<!--\s*end\s*-->)`

thanks rrrr