# Java returning a substring

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm returning some data from a database that looks like this

`<[<language><text xml:lang="">Automation1406741539346</text></language>]>`

What would be the easiest and best way I can remove everything from this string except Automation1406741539346?

Comment: regex is probably the best way. look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335250/parsing-xml-with-regex-in-java)

Comment: `String s = "Automation1406741539346";`

Comment: @jcjunction I like this quote from the page you link to: "Using regexes to parse XML always ends in tears."

Comment: @MicahSmith nobody said it was fun. ha. I use C# usually which has great tools for XML parsing.

Comment: A quick google lead me to this: ["How to parse or read XML File in Java"](http://javarevisited.blogspot.mx/2011/12/parse-xml-file-in-java-example-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s= "<[<language><text xml:lang=\"\">Automation1406741539346</text></language>]>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<text.*?>(.*?)</text>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

O/P :

```
Automation1406741539346
```