# How to get internal attribute values of xml

Tags: java, xml

I need to get `Device` `ID`, `DeviceType`, data of first `LastKnownValue` tag. The XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <DeviceList Devid="" Count="35">
    <Device ID="01">
      <Name>@@@@@</Name>
      <DeviceType>Me</DeviceType>
      <ValueVariables Count="3">
        <LastKnownValue Index="1" EndPoint="1" Name="STATE" Type="Bool">false</LastKnownValue>
        <LastKnownValue Index="2" EndPoint="1" Name="LOW BATTERY" Type="Bool">0</LastKnownValue>
        <LastKnownValue Index="3" EndPoint="1" Name="TAMPER" Type="Bool">false</LastKnownValue>
      </ValueVariables>
    </Device>
 </DeviceList>
```

I tried the following code, but unable to get the values of the attributes.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse("xml path");
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList devicelist =   doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("Device");
System.out.println(devicelist.getLength());
for (int i = 0; i < devicelist.getLength(); ++i) 
{
        Element rule = (Element) devicelist.item(i);
        //Device ID
        String ruleid = rule.getAttribute("ID");
        System.out.println(ruleid);
}
```

Comment: As you see code in your comment is not that easy to read. So instead of posting it in comment use [[edit]] option to update your post and place it there with proper formatting.

Comment: Excuse me, why don't you use an XPath query?!

Comment: I am unfamiliar to Xpath, please help me to get those attribute values.

Comment: You can find an example of use of XPath in this SO answer: [Get an Array or List of Strings between some Strings (Search multiple Strings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694064/get-an-array-or-list-of-strings-between-some-strings-search-multiple-strings/29694279#29694279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use [XPath](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/) to fetch the node values directly from XML instead of traverse and get desired node.

If `Device` node occurs only once then you can use below XPath expressions to fetch the data.

`XPath` to get `Device ID` is - `//*/Device/@ID` or `/DeviceList/Device/@ID`

`XPath` to get `DeviceType` is - `//*/DeviceType` or `/DeviceList/Device/DeviceType`

`XPath` to get first `LastKnownValue` - `(//*/LastKnownValue)[1]`

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you can use an XPath query that will extract information directly from the `doc`.

Try to have a look at [this link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/).

Here an example of code:

```
try {
   // Build structures to parse the String
   DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
   // Create an XPath query
   XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
   // Query the DOM object with the query 
   NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//hello").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: It is displaying following error:-[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: Are you sure that tour XML is a valid one?

Answer (score 1):

Completely functional example using JAXB:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(DeviceList.class);
    Unmarshaller um = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
    DeviceList deviceList = (DeviceList) um.unmarshal(new File("example.xml"));
    for (Device device : deviceList.devices) {
        System.out.println(device.id);
        System.out.println(device.deviceType);
        if (device.valueVariables.lastKnownValues.size() > 0) {
            LastKnownValue lkv = device.valueVariables.lastKnownValues.get(0);
            System.out.println(lkv.value);
        }
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="DeviceList")
public class DeviceList {
    @XmlAttribute(name="Devid")
    public String devid;
    @XmlAttribute(name="Count")
    public Integer count;
    @XmlElement(name="Device")
    public List<Device> devices;
}

public class Device {
    @XmlAttribute(name="ID")
    public String id;
    @XmlElement(name="Name")
    public String name;
    @XmlElement(name="DeviceType")
    public String deviceType;
    @XmlElement(name="ValueVariables")
    public ValueVariables valueVariables;
}

public class ValueVariables {
    @XmlAttribute(name="Count")
    public Integer count;
    @XmlElement(name="LastKnownValue")
    public List<LastKnownValue> lastKnownValues;
}

public class LastKnownValue {
    @XmlAttribute(name="Index")
    public Integer index;
    @XmlAttribute(name="EndPoint")
    public Integer endPoint; // maybe a String?
    @XmlAttribute(name="Name")
    public String name;
    @XmlAttribute(name="Type")
    public String type;
    @XmlValue
    public String value;
}
```