# Regexp from one html structure to another

Tags: php, regex

I want to convert html of this kind:

```
<h2>heading1</h2>
something1
<h2>heading2</h2>
something2
...
```

to

```
<li>
<div class="a">
heading1
</div>
<div class="b">
something1
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="a">
heading2
</div>
<div class="b">
something2
</div>
</li>
...
```

I think there should be some proper regexp (in PHP) for this job.
I tried `/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>(.*?)(<h2>)?/s` but that doesn't work.

Comment: You can't use RegEx to process Xml/Html ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/335446/5040941

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that regex is the right tool for this task?! 'Cause [it isn't.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: The famous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/993169

Comment: Are you sure you need to did using regex only if not in PHP Using the class `DOMDocument` easy to did this.

Comment: It's a shame someone can't just fix RegEx so it can do this job. (Joke).

Comment: Use anything to parse it that isn't regex.

Comment: I would also add that removing heading tags decrease the quality of your website referencement (see [Google's search engine optimization starter guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/fr//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf), **Use heading tags appropriately**).

Comment: @paul-bain haha, this is funny)

Comment: Your regex didn't work, because `(<h2>)?` if present is consumed already making it impossible to match the subsequent `<h2>`. Using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=`... <h2 or end `)` would maintain the position.